# Creating in Python script that read lines and count each empty and resets each time it finds not empty line

Tags: python

I am trying to create a python script that reads the empty lines and resets each time it finds populated line, then outputs to each line results

```
EXAMPLE:
13369
20901

29001


29002


RESULT:
1
1
2
1
2
3
1
2
```

To clarify again, what I try to do is read each line, and count until it finds result on line, then again reset the counting and do the same... it can be seen in example and result.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import io
import codecs
import re

indexes = open("box.txt", "r")
number = 0
with io.open(str(sys.argv[1]), 'r', encoding='utf-16-le') as file :
    filedata = file.read()

for line in indexes:
  # first = x[0:x.find('')]

  if not line.strip():
        number = 0
  else:
        number += 1


  #second = x[x.find(':')+1:len(x)-1]
  print (number)
  #filedata = filedata.replace(first, second)

#output = codecs.open("./translated/" + str(sys.argv[1]), 'w', 'utf-16-le')
#newdata = re.sub("\r?\n", "\r\n", filedata)
#output.write(newdata)
```

Comment: Can you also show what you have tried so far ?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Welcome to SO, pls explain your question properly with suitable example and code snippet that you have worked on.

Comment: ```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import io
import codecs
import re

indexes = open("box.txt", "r")
number = 0
with io.open(str(sys.argv[1]), 'r', encoding='utf-16-le') as file :
 filedata = file.read()

for line in indexes:
  # first = x[0:x.find('')]
  
  if not line.strip():
  number = 0
  else:
  number += 1


  #second = x[x.find(':')+1:len(x)-1]
  print (number)
  #filedata = filedata.replace(first, second)
 
#output = codecs.open("./translated/" + str(sys.argv[1]), 'w', 'utf-16-le')
#newdata = re.sub("\r?\n", "\r\n", filedata)
#output.write(newdata)
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include your code instead of posting it in comments.

Comment: Ok, I did add my current code, but something is flawed in it.. it either display 000000 al the time or it counts all the lines..

Answer (score 1):

According to your output

```
1
1
2
1
2
3
1
2
```

You need to modify your `if` statement

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import io
import codecs
import re

indexes = open("box.txt", "r")
number = 1
with io.open(str(sys.argv[1]), 'r', encoding='utf-16-le') as file :
   filedata = file.read()

for line in indexes:

   if line.strip():
      number = 1 # reset the counter if line is found
   else:
      number += 1 # if line not found, increment

   print (number)
```

Hope this answers your question!!

Comment: Can u check your text file whether it has empty lines or you could print indexes before for loop to cross verify

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems that once fixed allowed your script to work for me.

1. Get rid of the not on `line.strip()`

So it should be `if line.strip():`

2. Your expected output starts with 1 but in your loop you set number to zero.

So put `number = 1`

I also commented out that `with` statement since I just used `box.txt` locally when I was testing.

Comment: Okay, well something is wrong with your text file probably then. Try to creating a new one. Just copy and paste the exact example input.